# Leetcode: Remove duplicates from sorted array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Why does my solution work in the console but not on leetcode?

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let res = [];     
    for(let num of nums) {
        if(res.includes(num) === false) {
            res.push(num);
        }
    }   
    return res.length;
};
```

Console:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuQaj.png)

Leetcode:

```
let arr = [1, 1, 2]

removeDuplicates(arr) // 3
```

Comment: have you tried using If(res.indexOf(num) < 0) ? instead of if(res.includes(num) === false)

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing `includes` to `indexOf`, may be `includes` is not working in your environment. Also, instead of returning `length` you should return `res`.

Just in case you want to try another approach, you can look at `Sets` like below

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    return [...new Set(nums)]
};

console.log(removeDuplicates([1,1,2]))

console.log(removeDuplicates([1,1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Yes @YosvelQuintero just realised that. :)

Comment: Sets can take arrays of inputs directly

Comment: Edited. Thank you @YosvelQuintero.

Comment: Good to help.. Removing my answer because yours was first

Comment: That's so kind of you @YosvelQuintero. That's why I love SO, people are so willing to promote fellow learners. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use sortness properly. Algorithmically it is more effective to compare item with previous one, so complexity is `O(N)`.

Perhaps JS has some high-order function like Python `groupby` to make shorter code, but described method is definitely the best possible from algorithmical point of view.

[ideone](https://ideone.com/dZvxZG)

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let res = []; 
    let last = NaN
    for(i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] != last) {
            res.push(nums[i]);
            last = nums[i];
        }
    }   
    return res.length;
};

let arr = [1, 1, 2]
print(removeDuplicates(arr)) 

>>2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution you can try...

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
  let p1 = 0,lastVal =nums[0] -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   if (nums[i] != lastVal) {
    nums[p1] = nums[i];
    lastVal = nums[i]
    p1 +=1;
  }
 }
nums.length = p1;
console.log(nums);
};

let arr = [1, 1, 2]
removeDuplicates(arr);
```

[Click here to RUN](https://repl.it/@jaymanale/RemoveDuplicates)